# $\mathbb Z [\frac{1}{2}]$ and $\mathbb Z [\frac{1}{3}]$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

Here is a question:

Show that the additive subgroups of $\mathbb Z [\frac{1}{2}]$ and $\mathbb Z [\frac{1}{3}]$ are not isomorphic. Where $\mathbb Z [\frac{1}{n}] = \{ \frac{a}{n^k} | a, k \in \mathbb Z\}$

This is a trial, consider the isomorphism $\phi(\frac{a}{2^k}) = \frac{a}{3^k},$ then upon taking $a = 2 $ and $k = 1$ we get $\phi(1) = \frac{2}{3}$ which is a contradiction to $\phi$ being a ring isomorphism.

Is this trial correct? I am worried because the statement of the question said additive subgroups but I used a ring homomorphism instead.

Am I correct?

Comment: Can you clarify the problem statement? Do you want to show that $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[1/3]$ are not isomorphic as groups? Also, your attempted method cannot be correct because one cannot show a non-existence of an isomorphism by proposing a specific map and saying it doesn't work. What if there was another map, different from the one you wrote, that induced an isomorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think your argument is correct, exactly for the reason you state. It seems like the problem wants you to work in the category of groups, in which case $1$ need not go to $1$. Instead notice that $1$ is infinitely $2-$divisible in $\mathbb Z\left[\frac12\right]$, but $\mathbb Z\left[\frac13\right]$ does not contain any infinitely $2-$divisible element.

Comment: What do you mean? can you show it concretly please?

Comment: I do not see why 1 is infinitely $2$-divisible

Comment: I also do not see why the other ring does not contain any infinitely 2 divisible element

Comment: I got the first part but not the second

Comment: 1 = 2(1/2) = 2^2(1/4) ........ but how this ruins the isomorphism we have?

Comment: @Mathstupid, por any $k\in\mathbb Z\;\land\;k\geqslant0$, there exists $a=2^k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $1=\frac a{2^k}$, so $1$ can be obtained in infinite different ways in $\mathbb Z\left[\frac12\right]$.

Comment: Yeah I saw this but also one can be obtained if we divide by 3 infinitely many times in the other group

Comment: @Mathstupid, for that reason in $\mathbb Z\left[\frac13\right]$ there do **not** exist infinitely $2-$divisible elements but there do exist infinitely $3-$divisible elements.

Comment: got it thank you!$